# Unable to verify two arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to validate two array and its values. Scenario is I will get json array from my api response and I need to read that and verify with the declared values which will be expected values.

Here are the following code-

```
String jsonread = approveCampaign.prettyPrint();
org.json.JSONArray arrayobj = new org.json.JSONArray(jsonread);

String[] myStringArray;
myStringArray = new String[]{"IND", "PRI", "PUB", "NON"};

//String[] enums = getNames(entityType.class);     // fetching values from declared ENUMS
String[] EnTypes= new String[0];    // Intializing array to store response array values

for (int i = 0; i < arrayobj.length(); i++) {
    log.info("Response ENUMS are following\n" + arrayobj.getString(i));
    EnTypes= new String[arrayobj.length()];
    EnTypes[i] = String.valueOf(i);    // assigning values of response array to EnTypes
}

if (Arrays.equals(myStringArray, EnTypes)) {
    log.log(Status.PASS, "Values in array matched!");
} else {
    log.log(Status.FAIL, "Values in array doesnot match");
}
```

The above code always says values are not matching not sure why. I want to assert the myStringArray with EnTypes

I appreciate your help in advance.

> Edited- Here is the jsonread data- [
>       "IND",
>       "PRI",
>       "PUB",
>       "NON" ]

Comment: Have you printed out both the arrays before you compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
 String jsonread = approveCampaign.prettyPrint();
    org.json.JSONArray arrayobj = new org.json.JSONArray(jsonread);

    String[] myStringArray;
    myStringArray = new String[]{"IND", "PRI", "PUB", "NON"};


     EnTypes= new String[arrayobj.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayobj.length(); i++) {
            log.info("Response ENUMS are following\n" + arrayobj.getString(i));
            EnTypes[i] = arrayobj.getString(i);            // assigning values of response array to EnTypes
        }
        Arrays.sort(myStringArray);
        Arrays.sort(EnTypes);
        if (Arrays.equals(myStringArray, EnTypes)) {
            log.log(Status.PASS, "Values in array matched!");
        } else {
            log.log(Status.FAIL, "Values in array doesnot match");
        }
 }
```

Comment: It is better if you add the explanation to your answer by editing it rather than having it as comments.

Comment: Quick question though- does the values has to be like this as declared. Because,, it should not fail if order changes

Comment: It fails when, the order of myStringArray changes. Because, order of myStringArray or jsonread data might change and it be able to compare the values!